# TFS - User can only see certain branches within a Team Project

Tags: tfs

I have set up security in TFS 2012 Team Projects. There is one user who can see parts of a Team Project (certain branches) that he otherwise should not see. I have checked the branch security as well and can't find anywhere why that user should have access to it. It also shows a weird plus sign in front of that Team Project for that user only where he can only see some branches and not the full team project.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. apparently user had checked out some files before we restricted the permissions and therefore once the user checked in their changes, they could not see these projects anymore.